# Assign new values for pixels

Tags: python, r, r-raster

for any raster data set, l would like to assign `1` for max pixel values and `0` for others in a row.

l tried many things but l could not find any solution so far.

here is an example code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
ras=raster("D:/Rtool/DATA/DigitalTerrainModel/SJER2013_DTM.tif")
```

this raster has  `5060 col and 4299 row` .what l want is to assign `"1"` for rowMax value and `"0"` for others.

l tried :

```
df=data.frame(ras[])

summarise_each(df, funs(max(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

however,l got only one max value for whole raster elevation values, that is not what l want.

on python, l used `df.eq(df.max(1), 0).astype(int)` so how can l do samething on R?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Data Preparation**

```
# Load packages
library(raster)

## Create example raster layer

# create an empty raster layer
r <- raster(ncol = 10, nrow = 10)
# assign values to cells
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
# Inspect the raster layer
plot(r)
```

**Solution 1**: This solution uses functions from the `raster` and the `dplyr` package.

```
library(dplyr)

# extract values as matrix, and then converted to data frame
data_df <- as.data.frame(values(r, format = "matrix"))

# Calculate the maximum and save the values to the "Max" column
data_df$Max <- apply(data_df, 1, max)

# Define a function to replace the values to be 1 or zero
# x is the input vector, M is the maximum
max_replace <- function(x, M){
  x[x != M] <- 0
  x[x == M] <- 1
  return(x)
}

# Use mutate_each to replace values to be 1 and 0
data_df2 <- data_df %>%
  dplyr::mutate_each(funs(max_replace(., M = Max)), - Max) %>%
  dplyr::select(-Max)

# Assign the values back to the raster layer
values(r) <- as.matrix(data_df2)

# Examine the results
plot(r)
```

**Solution 2**: This only uses `raster` package

```
# Initialize an empty list to store the results of each row
raster_list <- list()

# A for loop to crop the image and assign 0 or 1 to see if it is the maximum of that row

for (i in 1:nrow(r)){
  # Get the extent of each row
  temp_ext <- extent(r, r1 = i, r2 = i, c1 = 1, c2 = ncol(r))
  # Crop the raster for only one row
  temp_r <- crop(r, temp_ext)
  # Get the maximum of one row
  temp_max <- max(values(temp_r), na.rm = TRUE)
  # Use raster algebra
  temp_r[temp_r != temp_max] <- 0
  temp_r[temp_r == temp_max] <- 1

  # Save the results to the raster_list
  raster_list <- c(raster_list, temp_r)

}

# Merge all rasters
m <- do.call(merge, raster_list)

# Examine the result
plot(m)
```

Comment: l tried your code but all elevation values get assigned as "0". each row has a max value ,when l tried your code, it take a max value and only one value decide others. what l want is the code go in each row,find max value and assigned as 1 ,then others 0 and do samething for other rows.

Comment: @omersan I have updated my solution. Now the solution uses function from the package `dplyr`. Please test it to see if it is useful.

Comment: @ömersarı I also applied another solution only needs the `raster` package.

Comment: thanks.it works perfect. l m new at R and still l m trying to familiar with some code type

Comment: @ömer sarı Great. Do you know which solution is faster when you work on your raster image?

Comment: solution 2 & solution1 are working without an error.my raster data is big and it takes some time to give a result.both ,almost same.l can not say which one actually is faster.after getting the result ,l use arcgis to classify the image and to see the result as plot does not give particular result.

Answer (score 3):

Hope this helps.

```
# create fake raster
fakeRaster <- raster(matrix(ncol = 10, nrow = 10))

# place values 1 to number of cells; so the right most value
# of each row should be the highest
values(fakeRaster) <- 1:ncell(fakeRaster)

# introduce higher values somewhere; test points
values(fakeRaster)[75] <- 300
values(fakeRaster)[1] <- 300
values(fakeRaster)[100] <- 300
values(fakeRaster)[81] <- 300
values(fakeRaster)[45] <- 300

# extract values as matrix
dataRaster <- values(fakeRaster, format = "matrix")

# get every row; evalute if equal to max, if yes give 1, if no give 0
# then transpose the output
dataRaster <- t(apply(dataRaster, 1, FUN = function(x) ifelse(x == max(x, na.rm = T), 1, 0) ))

# reassign value to raster
values(fakeRaster) <- dataRaster
```

BTW, when you do:

```
df=data.frame(ras[])
```

You end up with a vector (I think), which gave you problem. You can try the as well the values(raster, format = "matrix") that I used in the above example.

Comment: thanks but each row has its own max value and this value must be used to assign 1 and others 0 .l tried your code as well but like above answer,one max value used to compare with other values in each row and that is why whole matrix become 0.each row must have a max value

Comment: @din reply seems correct to me. it gives you "1" in correspondance to the max of each row, "0" elsewhere. Or are you asking for something differnt ?

Comment: that was what l m asking but it does not give the result what l expect .

Comment: Maybe post an example data of yours and expected result.

Comment: @ömersarı All good. But, I believe it should give the same result with the above codes. If there will be an edit, it will be in the max in apply, where na.rm = TRUE; BTW, I also check the run time for the three codes; Code 1 : 1.401822 secs, Code 2 : 1.395232 secs (first codes)
Code 3 : 0.08543992 secs (code in this answer); But all good, as long as you find your answer. Cheers!

Comment: you should be right. if you still are interested in it,l will add an example data.

Comment: let me try your code again.l m wondering the dem could be corrupted as after your code ,l replaced it with new one as l overwrote it before

Comment: you are right .it works with similar data type. Sorry for my mistake. l checked the DEM which l used before ,all values were "0" but with new DEM as you said,it gave the result that l need.